# if we apply if len(numbers)%2: and if numbers are coming odd then it will execute if block or else block

Tags: python-3.x

```
if len(numbers)%2:
    middle_index=len(numbers)//2
    return middle_index

else:
    middle_index=len(numbers)
```

if the length of numbers is even then it will execute if block or else block?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read about posts formating [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and edit your question to be more readable.

Comment: It will run else part